# Running crontab in mac

Tags: macos, cron

I'm trying to test a python script that has to be run by a cron job. I'm trying to config the cron job in my mac but doesn't run. Here is my cron job...

```
*   *   *   *   *   user /usr/local/bin/python3 ~/Documents/wpc/stocks/daily_stock.py
```

If I `crontab -l` the job is there. I ran the script manually and works but is not running by the cron job. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following method to solve this issue on Mac OS.

You can add a shebang to the top of your python script to specify the Python versions path:

> **Python 3**
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python3
> ```
>
> **Python 2.7**
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python2
> ```

You will also need to ensure the file is **executable**:

```
chmod a+x filename.py
```

This will allow you to execute the python script without having to specify "python" before the script.

You can then set your crontab with `crontab -e`, e.g:

```
0 9/15 * * *  cd /Users/user12/Dev/Scripts/Python && ./test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find error message at mail, use `mail` command find it.

If there is an "operation not permitted" error

maybe you have to add cron to the Full Disk Access apps (Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access apps/execs).
And click + button, go to /usr/sbin, double click the **cron** file.

then crontab can use your script