# Executing python script with cron job from MacOS

Tags: python, macos, cron

I am trying to create a very simple Cron job on MacOS to execute a Python script.

My Cron job :

```
* * * * * usr/bin/python3 /Users/gaetan/Desktop/createfolder.py
```

When I run the script from the terminal is working fine but from cron is not doing anything.

I don't understand what could be the error, I have given all the rights and double check the path.

Comment: A missing `/` prefixing the python3 path?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: You have a typo, `usr/bin/python3` looks in your home directory for a directory named `usr` and withing that for `bin` and within that for `python3`. You mean `/usr/bin/python3`. (But also note that `cron` is not enabled by default on macOS.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running crontab in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854500/running-crontab-in-mac)

Comment: @progmatico Thanks, added to the script but still not working. 
flaxel > That was the answer I tried but was not successful

Comment: Try to put your py file in the home directory, instead of desktop and simply refer it by filename instead of full path. As per a @chepner comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329813/crontab-wont-run-python-on-mac-os?rq=1) it looks mac os searches the file there (or maybe in the specified path from there)

Answer (score 0):

on Mac and linux, the crontab syntax is same!
But i suggest not to manipulate your crontab with default system for some reason.

As you are using `python` You can use `celery` It will save your huge time schedule task: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: I am sorry but this does not help at all. 
Plus before using some tools I must master the basics

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use `cron` on macOS. First step grant the binary permissions over your full disk.

[image: cron on macOS privacy]

Second, be sure you check for a full path to *everything* - your python executable is not correct in the question as it needs to start with `/usr/...`

[Here is an answer on a partner site specific to Apple operating systems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402299/5472) with details on debugging and privacy controls if you’d like more help.